# Searching for Android apps by permissions, features and intents

Tags: android, google-play, android-intent

Are there services out there that let the user search or browse an Android app market by specifying the app's permissions (e.g. `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`), features (e.g. `android.hardware.microphone`), launched or filtered intents (e.g. `android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`)?

I am interested in locating 3rd party apps that could complement my app in the Android environment so that I could recommend such apps to my users, ideally programmatically. What I've used so far is Google Code Search queries such as http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=RECOGNIZE_SPEECH, but these cover only open source apps. Is there a better way?

*Update*: note that Google Code Search has meanwhile been shut down. Sad. It was a really useful service.

Comment: You need to crawl all apps on the store, or download all apps and analyze the permissions in the Manifest file. Alternatively search on Google for "App Intelligence API" services that do all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this.
The only way I see is to build your own crawler with
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested, I've developed an app, StripSearch, to filter search listings by the permissions used. The app works by excluding results that don't meet the permission requirements specified by a given search filter (a filter can exclude, require, or ignore specific permissions). Several filters are included by default, but you can create your own as well.

Get StripSearch here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasslefixes.stripsearch

If you want to see a demo explaining its usage, you can watch a video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mynw3rbky5A

StripSearch is free, does not include ads or spyware, and only uses the following permissions:

- android.permission.INTERNET (obviously needed to search the store)
- com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES (needed to obtain the Google Play Android ID tied to your phone and account)

Giv it a try!

Comment: Sadly, this app no longer seems to work on my Android 5.1 device. I presume a google services update broke it and now I just get an "Auth token rejected" error when trying to search.